# Target element within specific element domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to target a tags with class `genre` within parent div with id `test`:

```
<div id="test">
   <a class="genre">hello</a>
   <a class="genre">hello2</a>
</div>
```

So far, I can get all the `genre` a tags:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//a[@class="genre"]');
```

... but I want to adjust `//a[@class="genre"]` so I only target the ones within the `test` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you did not write it yourself because you use all needed elements of xpath in your expression. Or, maybe, i've misunderstand you question

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@id="test"]/a[@class="genre"]');
```

Comment: I am entry level on this. Thanks. Will accept in a moment.